# How to build a list of vectors taken from an other list that satisfy a constraint

Tags: z3py

It's my first try with z3.

I want to find which vectors taken in a list I have to sum to get a given result.

I've try this but that don't compile because R isn't an indice.

```
Tr_tuple = ((-1,1,0,1,0,0,0,-1),
      (1,-1,1,0,0,0,-1,0),
      (0,-1,-1,1,0,1,0,0),
      (-1,0,1,-1,0,0,0,0),
      (0,0,0,-1,-1,1,0,1),
      (0,0,-1,0,1,-1,1,0),
      (0,1,0,0,0,-1,-1,1),
      (1,0,0,0,-1,0,1,-1),
      (1,1,-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1), 
      (-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1))

Start_tuple = (1,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,1)
depth = 2

G = [Int('g_%s' % i) for i in range(8)]
R = [Int('r_%s' % i) for i in range(depth)]

R_c = [ And (R[i] >= 0, R[i] < 10) for i in range(depth) ]   
G_c = [G[i] == Start_tuple[i] + sum([ Tr_tuple[j][i] for j in R]) for i in range(8)]
G_g = [G[i] == 0 for i in range(8)]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found something but it's like brute force :

```
M = [[Int('m_%s_%s' % (j,i)) for i in range(8)] for j in range(depth)]

T = [Int('t_%s' % i) for i in range(8)]

M_c = And([
        Or([
          And([M[j][i] == Tr_tuple[k][i] for i in range(8)])
                for k in range(10)])
                    for j in range(depth)])

G_c = (And([Start_tuple[i]+sum([M[j][i] for j in range(depth)]) == 0 for i in range(8)]))

s = Solver()
s.add(M_c)
s.add(G_c)      
if s.check() == sat :
    pp(s.model())
else:
    print('No solution found')
```

Comment: Is `No solution found` the expected outcome?

Comment: If so, wouldn't it be better to have an example which has a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't search enough deeper to find a solution or there isn't. If you put `Start_tuple = (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)` you'll get an obvious solution as `Tr_tuple[8]and[9]` do the opposite transformation.

Comment: Do you want exactly 2 elements from `Tr_tuple` to be taken? (Taking just the first element, which is the negation of the original `Start_tuple`, would otherwise be a solution.)

Comment: No I can't easily choose the starting point. This is a kind of puzzle : you have a stating point, a set of transformations and a goal. The question is which transformations must be apply to reach the goal.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question "Do you want exactly 2 elements from Tr_tuple to be taken?" and why otherwise this code of which you say "I found something" doesn't yield the solution with just `Tr_tuple[0]`, which would reach the goal of all zeros (or what other goal do you have here?).